# undefined method `save_item' for ItemsController:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this method in my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def save_item(asin, domain, user_id)
    ...
  end
end
```

& when I try to call it in items_controller.rb by rails runner 'ItemsController.rss'

```
  def self.rss
    self.save_item(@item_registration.asin, @item_registration.domain, @item_registration.user_id)
    ...
  end
```

I'm getting this error

> `.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@jogg/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in`
>   eval': undefined method `save_item' for ItemsController:Class
>   (NoMethodError)`

I also tried

```
Application.save_item(@item_registration.asin, @item_registration.domain, @item_registration.user_id)  &  ApplicationController... & just save_item(@item_registration.asin, @item_registration.domain, @item_registration.user_id)
```

& it does work in not SELF method, but not with SELF.some_method

Comment: you can't call an instance method from a class method. Saving objects is also not the responsibility of controllers.

Comment: I am able to call it in other controllers. Like in controller categories_controller.rb 
def create
save_item(@item_registration.asin, @item_registration.domain, @item_registration.user_id)
...

Comment: because that's an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: Thank you. How can I call it in the same "ApplicationController"? I'm getting error undefined method `save_item' for ApplicationController:Class (NoMethodError) & both my methods in the same file application_controller.rb

Comment: You might implement the method "save_item" in a helper or lib module, and "extend" the helper or lib module into this class. For fast test, maybe you can try to call "ApplicationController.new.save_item". But I think it's maybe not a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def self.rss
    self.save_item(@item_registration.asin, @item_registration.domain,      @item_registration.user_id)
    ...
end
```

is a class method. The self in `self.save_item` truned into the class `ApplicationController`, not a instance of `ApplicationController`.

But `save_item` is a instance method of `ApplicationController`. The receiver of the method should be a instance of `ApplicationController`, so can't be `ApplicationController` **class**.